# Dell D630 speaker/microphone->headset jack converter?

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude

The Dell D630 has two seperate 3.5mm microphone/speaker jacks.  I know there has to be an adapter to fit a combined 4-pole 3.5mm plug for a headset, yes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I picked up one of [these](http://support.radioshack.com/productinfo/DocumentResults.asp?sku_id=26-204&Name=Input%20Device%20Accessories&Reuse=N) long ago, but it's probably more suited to a desktop machine. Nowadays I just use [this](http://www.plantronics.com/north_america/en_US/products/cat1150057/cat5420035/prod29780013) though.